# I2C driver changes to recognize multiple buses

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, i2c, u-boot, kbuild

We have defined the analog videoIn **adv7180** metadata hardware definition in the **i2c2** node in one iMX device tree file. The ultimate aim is to recognize adv7180 driver from the i2c2 bus.

During the boot process of the processor using the linux image made with defconfig changes for I2C, the second I2C bus is not getting recognized.

Given below are the serial console print statements:

```
U-Boot 2015.10+fslc+g1b6aee7 (Jan 16 2018 - 14:57:01 +0530)

CPU: Freescale i.MX6Q rev1.2 996 MHz (running at 792 MHz)
CPU: Automotive temperature grade (-40C to 125C) at 26C
Reset cause: POR
Board: MX6-SabreSD
I2C: ready

Line 129: i2c i2c-1: IMX I2C adapter registered   //i2c-2 not registered??

Line 272 onwards: i2c /dev entries driver 
IR NEC protocol handler initialized 
IR RC5(x) protocol handler initialized 
IR RC6 protocol handler initialized 
IR JVC protocol handler initialized 
IR Sony protocol handler initialized 
IR RC5 (streamzap) protocol handler initialized 
IR SANYO protocol handler initialized 
IR MCE Keyboard/mouse protocol handler initialized 
mxc_v4l2_output v4l2_out.28: V4L2 device registered as video16 
mxc_v4l2_output v4l2_out.28: V4L2 device registered as video17 
i2c-core: driver [mag3110] using legacy suspend method 
i2c-core: driver [mag3110] using legacy resume method
```

I have written these extra lines in defconfig files in the source directory of my Yocto Built.

```
CONFIG_IMX_HAVE_PLATFORM_IMX_I2C=y
# CONFIG_I2C_COMPAT is not set
CONFIG_I2C_CHARDEV=y
# CONFIG_I2C_HELPER_AUTO is not set
CONFIG_I2C_ALGOPCF=m
CONFIG_I2C_ALGOPCA=m
CONFIG_I2C_ALGOBIT=y
CONFIG_I2C_IMX=y
CONFIG_I2C_MUX=y
CONFIG_I2C_MUX=y
```

I have also check Kconfig files and seen that i2c driver is passed from the kernel-source directory in the built.

Do I have to make modifications to the C-files (**driver files**) made in the path `/home/fsl-community-bsp-myproject/build/tmp/work-shared/imx6qonlinepdd/kernel-source/drivers/i2c` of my yocto built?

There is even a C file for adv7180 in the sub-directory **/drivers/media** , can it be modified?

Comment: It seems that you're passing a wrong dtb to the kernel (`mag3110` is being probed over i2c, i2c-1 but no i2c-2 is being registered...). How are you telling Yocto/U-Boot/kernel to use your dtb?

Comment: I have declared the .dtb file name in the machine folder in sources directory. What do you mean by passing a wrong dtb? I have mentioned the name 'imx6q-sabresd-ldo.dtb' in the machine folder.

Comment: I mean that it is highly likely that you're not passing the kernel your modified dtb but the default one. Can you paste those configurations as well as their paths? You're not doing any change in `whatever/build/tmp/work-shared/...`, aren't you? If you are, you shouldn't. Unless you know exactly what are you doing. As its name states, is a temporal (`tmp`) folder, the changes could volatilize.

Comment: You guessed it right. I am tampering with the tmp folder, and replacing the dts and dtsi files to get some changes in the dtb file, which can recognize some drivers, but it is not working. I have even tried to see modules.dep file in /lib/modules/kernel, and the drivers that I need are not written in these files.

Comment: What commands are you using to rebuild your image after modifying `tmp`?

Comment: bitbake -c cleansstate myproject-image ;
bitbake -c compile -f linux-fslc-imx-myproject ;
bitbake -c deploy linux-fslc-imx-myproject ;
bitbake myproject-image ;
I am replacing the dts and the c files after compiling the kernel again.

Comment: You should do it before recompiling the kernel. Otherwise your changes won't be taken into account. You can also use `bitbake virtual/kernel -C compile` after making your changes in `tmp`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the changes were reflected in the kernel built in tmp.

Comment: Did you add `CONFIG_MXC_TVIN_ADV7180` option?

Comment: @Nayfe , yes I have added that too.

Answer (score 2):

you should look in the device tree you're using if i2c bus 2 is enabled.

You need to add the folowing line in your dts :

```
&i2c2 { // Change the name as needed 
    status = "okay"; 

    pinctrl-names = "default";
}
```

You've probably status = "disabled"; in the i2c node you're seeking.

EDIT: 
At first glance provided dts (https://pastebin.com/Y0esXmaX) seems ok. In order to debug further, one shall look into /dev/ directory in order to find the i2c bus.

As an example :

```
root@pico-imx8mq:~# ls /dev/*i2c*
/dev/i2c-0  /dev/i2c-1  /dev/i2c-2
```

This means I have 3 i2c bus and I can find them all on my dts. If you don't have the bus there you probably do have a dts problem.

`dmesg | grep i2c` might also give some hints.

You can also use i2cdetect from i2ctools package :

```
root@pico-imx8mq:~# i2cdetect -y 0 ## that will detect devices on first i2c bus
root@pico-imx8mq:~# i2cdetect -y 1 ## that will detect devices on second i2c bus
root@pico-imx8mq:~# i2cdetect -y 2 ## that will detect devices on third i2c bus
```

Comment: I have already made the changes at the device tree level. I have even added pmic ,pinctrl and videoin adv7180. The dts files are reflected during the bitbake, as I checked the dtb file compiled with the kernel in yocto, and found i2c2 node enabled.

Comment: Can you add a link to your dts ? (pastebin if possible to your original question)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Y0esXmaX , this file contains the dts, other dts files I have kept same as imx6q-sabresd reference device.

Comment: You can try to use i2ctools in order to know whether the bus is actually detected, or just watch what you find of /dev/*i2c* you're supposed to find your i2c bus there.

Comment: i2ctools is not included while doing the OS build. I added the cross-compiled package of i2ctools but the executable was not runnable.

Comment: Then you should bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig and add the i2c options. However I'm quiet intrigued that your kernel configuration does not already use it, are you using proper yocto release for your board? 
In order to add the package in your image just add IMAGE_INSTALL +=" i2c-tools " to your image recipe or IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "  i2c-tools " to your local.conf